Is every Lie-super algebra special?
I will say that a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is special if there is an associative algebra $A$ such that $\mathfrak{g}$ is subalgebra of $A$ when its product is replaced by the commutator; which, in turn, makes $A$ a Lie algebra. By the PBW Theorem, every Lie algebra is special: in fact, $\mathfrak{g}$ can be seen as a Lie subalgebra of its universal enveloping algebras $U(\mathfrak{g})$ with comutator.
Now to the super case.
If $A$ is an associative super-algebra, it becomes an super-Lie algebra when we use the super-comutator. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a super-Lie algebra. I will say that $\mathfrak{g}$ is special if there is an associative super-algebra $A$ such that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a sub super-Lie algebra of $A$ when we consider it with super-comutator. In this setting, we have an enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ and a PBW theorem - so that $\mathfrak{g}$ can be seen as a subspace of $U(\mathfrak{g})$. However, the enveloping algebra of a Lie-super algebra in general is not a super-algebra; it is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded just as a vector space. So, the 'obvious' idea to show that every Lie super-algebra is special fails.
Hence, my question: is every Lie super-algera special?

What about using Ado'stheorem for Lie algebras (and Lie-super algebras)?

@DietrichBurde I want to inclued the case of infinite dimensional Lie-super algebras.
